deep keyof of a nested object in typescript
I want to create a custom table. The prop in the cell and footer in createColumnHelper function should return the correct object key/type instead of any.
For example, I have a nested object progress in my DATA. Or if not an object, it also should return the correct type.
I attached screenshots of how I see in the IDE
Helper.ts
import { ReactElement } from "react";

export type Column<T> = {
  header: string | (() => ReactElement);
  accessor: (row: T) => any;
  cell?:(prop: any) => ReactElement | string;
  footer?: (prop: any) => ReactElement | string;
};

export const createColumnHelper = <T>() => {
  return {
    accessor: (
      accessor: keyof T | ((row: T) => any),
      column: {
        header: string | (() => ReactElement);
        cell?: (prop: any) => ReactElement | string;
        footer?: (prop: any) => ReactElement | string;
      }
    ) => {
      return {
        header: column.header,
        accessor: (row: T) => (typeof accessor === "function" ? accessor(row) : row[accessor]),
        cell: column.cell,
        footer: column.footer,
      } as Column<T>;
    }
  };
};

TableComponents.tsx
import React from "react";
import { createColumnHelper } from "./columnHelper";

type Person = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  age: number
  visits: number
  status: string
  progress: {
    ok?: number;
    no?: string
  }
}

const DATA: Person[] = [
  {
    firstName: 'tanner',
    lastName: 'linsley',
    age: 24,
    visits: 100,
    status: 'In Relationship',
    progress: {
      ok: 50
    },
  },
  {
    firstName: 'tandy',
    lastName: 'miller',
    age: 40,
    visits: 40,
    status: 'Single',
    progress: {
      no: 'bad'
    },
  },
]

const columnHelper = createColumnHelper<Person>();

const columns = [
  columnHelper.accessor(
    'firstName', {
    header: 'First Name',
    cell: val => val,
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor(
    'progress', {
      header: 'Progress',
      cell: prop => prop.ok,
    }),
  columnHelper.accessor(row => row, {
    header: () => <span>Age</span>,
    cell: prop => <span>{prop.age}</span>,
  }),
];

const TableComponent: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
        {columns.map((column, index) => (
          <th key={index}>
            {typeof column.header === "function" ? column.header() : column.header}
          </th>
        ))}
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {DATA.map((row, rowIndex) => (
        <tr key={rowIndex}>
          {columns.map((column, colIndex) => (
            <td key={colIndex}>
              {column.cell ? column.cell(column.accessor(row)) : column.accessor(row)}
            </td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
      <tr>
        {columns.map((column, index) => (
          <td key={index}>
            {column.footer ? column.footer({ column }) : null}
          </td>
        ))}
      </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  );
};

export default TableComponent;




But you are using the type Column::cell: (prop: any) => ••• in the declaration. You want to type it differently so give it the type you wish for. If I’m not getting to your point, I will expand on it.

You have a lot of any in there, and if you start giving it correct types, then TS will get upset about things. Presumably you want Column<T, V> where V is the type of the output of accessor and the input of cell/footer. Splitting the difference between actual type safety and all-anys I suppose you can write this playground link, but that just pushes the any to the next part of your code. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz, yes, it seems like that’s what I need. The type of the output of accessor and the input of cell/footer. thank you

Since you care about the input type of cell/footer and the output type of accessor, you should consider adding a generic type parameter to Column for that type:
type Column<T, V> = {
  header: string | (() => ReactElement);
  accessor: (row: T) => V;
  cell?: (prop: V) => ReactElement | string;
  footer?: (prop: V) => ReactElement | string;
};

Then the value returned by createColumnHelper<T>() should have an accessor method that either accepts a value of type K extends keyof T and produces a Column<T, T[K]>, or it accepts a value of type (row: T) => V for some V and produces a Column<T, V>.  That looks like:
const createColumnHelper = <T,>() => {
  // call signatures
  function accessor<K extends keyof T>(
    accessor: K, column: Omit<Column<T, T[K]>, "accessor">
  ): Column<T, T[K]>;
  function accessor<V>(
    accessor: (row: T) => V, column: Omit<Column<T, V>, "accessor">
  ): Column<T, V>;

  // implementation
  function accessor(
    accessor: keyof T | ((row: T) => any), column: Omit<Column<T, any>, "accessor">
  ): Column<T, any> {
    return {
      header: column.header,
      accessor: (row: T) => (typeof accessor === "function" ? accessor(row) : row[accessor]),
      cell: column.cell,
      footer: column.footer,
    };
  }
  return { accessor };
};

Note that I'm using Omit to easily describe a Column with the accessor property missing. It's not necessary, but saves some writing over {header: ⋯, cell?: ⋯, footer?: ⋯}.  This fixes the problem you were having:
const columns = [
  columnHelper.accessor(
    'firstName', {
    header: 'First Name',
    cell: val => val,
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor(
    'progress', {
    header: 'Progress',
    cell: prop => String(prop.ok), 
  }),
  columnHelper.accessor(row => row, {
    header: () => <span>Age</span>,
    cell: prop => <span>{prop.age}</span>,
  }),
];

(and note that I had to fix a bug, since prop.ok is not a string or a ReactElement.)

That answers the question as asked, but if you do that, you'll run into problems with column.cell ? column.cell(column.accessor(row)) : column.accessor(row) and the like. The only reason why that used to work is because column.cell() accepts any. Now it doesn't. And TS can't verify this as valid because of the multiple utterances of column of a union type. This is ms/TS#30581 more or less, and the fixes for it are well out of scope for this question.
The easiest middle ground is to have columnHelper.accessor(a, o) require that the input look like Omit<Column<T, T[K]>, "accessor"> or Omit<Column<T, V>, "accessor">, but which returns a Column<T, any>:
const createColumnHelper = <T,>() => {
  // call signatures
  function accessor<K extends keyof T>(
    accessor: K, column: Omit<Column<T, T[K]>, "accessor">
  ): Column<T, any>;
  function accessor<V>(
    accessor: (row: T) => V, column: Omit<Column<T, V>, "accessor">
  ): Column<T, any>;

  // implementation
  function accessor(
    accessor: keyof T | ((row: T) => any), column: Omit<Column<T, any>, "accessor">
  ): Column<T, any> {
    return {
      header: column.header,
      accessor: (row: T) => (typeof accessor === "function" ? accessor(row) : row[accessor]),
      cell: column.cell,
      footer: column.footer,
    };
  }
  return { accessor };
};

That will make it easy to map over, but the any problem is still there in the output:
columns[0].cell?.(1) // no error

That should conceivably error with "number is not assignable to {ok?: number, no?: string}".  But it doesn't.  Oh well, you didn't ask about that, and fixing it would take a bunch more refactoring.
Playground link to code

Thank you!
Is it possible to remove any types everywhere? if in Person will be all strings?
{ ok?: string, no?: string }

The any issue has nothing to do with strings. It has to do with column.cell(column.accessor(row)) and ms/TS#30581. It would take a bunch of refactoring to deal with that, and it's out of scope here.
